# command to delete the oldest .tar file in a directory when a maximum count of .tar files is reached to 10

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting . I am trying to delete the oldest .tar in a directory when the count of .tar files reaches 10.(Every time server is restarted , I get a .tar file. So when count reaches 10, I should delete the oldest tar file).  Below is the code.

```
var=`find /aaa/bbb/ccc/ -type f -name "wranpcaLog_*.tar"  | wc -l`
echo "before loop"
echo $var

if [ ${var} -gt 10 ]
then
    $ find /aaa/bbb/ccc/wranpcaLog_*.tar | head -1 | xargs rm -rf
    #`find /var/opt/ericsson/nms_umts_wran_pca/ -type f -name "wranpcaLog_*.tar" | head -1`    
    #do
    # rm -r $i
    #   break
    # done
fi
```

Please help me in this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `logrotate`.

`logrotate` is used the program that manages your log files in `/var/log`.  Example to follow.  It can rotate logs based on date or size.

Look at /etc/cron.daily/logrotate and /etc/logrotate.conf. You should just be able to put an entry in /etc/logrotate.conf to handle the file your want to rotate.

Also see this website: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility

OK, so on my system /etc/cron.daily/logrotate calls logrotate once every day. /etc/logrotate.conf tells logrotate how to handle each file. So you only need to worry about modifying /etc/logrotate.conf

You should just have to add an entry like this to your /etc/logrotate.conf file.

```
/var/log/LOGFILENAME {
    monthly
    create 0664 root root
    rotate 1
}
```

Then restart your system or cron or however you make the changes take effect. You can also test your config file by calling logrotate directly, thusly:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

The line rotate 1 tells `logrotate` to keep one old copy so you will end up with two months worth of logs: the previous month and this month. Change rotate 1 to rotate 10 if you want to keep 10 copies of the file.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of keeping 10 files? Is it so you can see recent restarts, or is it based on time frame or ... something else?

Because I'd be thinking of using `find -mtime` specifically:

```
find /aaa/bbb/ccc/ -type f -name "wranpcaLog_*.tar" -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Which'll delete all files that haven't been modified for 10 days. (Modify to taste - it might be 1 day is more apt).

That way, you don't risk losing your really recent files because something is glitched and respawning too fast.

Comment: If I restart my server 10 times in one minute, then I would be getting 10 .tar files startung from zero.  when 11th time I restart,it should delete the first created .tar file. So instead of using timestamp is there any other better solution.  coz the requirement is too keep only a max of 10 .tar files

Comment: Keeping the 10 most recent files is quite difficult, hence why I'm asking, as it may be redundant. Bear in mind that your solution above - doesn't have any ordering on the deletion, so it's not necessarily the most recent 10 files you're keeping.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using most of your code :

```
var=$(find /aaa/bbb/ccc/ -type f -name "wranpcaLog_*.tar"  | wc -l)
echo "before loop"
echo $var

if [ ${var} -gt 10 ]
then
    find /aaa/bbb/ccc/ -type f -name "wranpcaLog_*.tar -printf '%A@ %p\n' |
        sort -n |
        awk 'END{$1=""; sub(/^ */, ""); system("rm "$0)}'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The weakness of your current approach is there's no particular file ordering. You don't necessarily keep the most recent 10 or the oldest 10. Do do that, you'd have to collate and sort.

So I'd be thinking something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $files_to_keep = 10;
my $path_to_prune = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/";

my %age_of;

sub stash_recent {
    next unless m/wranpcaLog_.*\.tar/;
    $age_of{$File::Find::name} = -M;
}

find( \&stash_recent, $path_to_prune );

my $count = 0;
foreach my $file ( sort { $age_of{$a} <=> $age_of{$b} } keys %age_of ) {
    next if $count++ < $files_to_keep;
    print "Delete $file\n";
}
```

It'll iterate the path you've suggested, looking for all files (recursively) which match your spec. Pick out file age. (Not modification time) and put that into a hash `%age_of`.

Then run through each element in that hash, and keep the 10 newest. (well, the script won't actually do anything, it'll just print - but that's because I won't embed deletion commmands into a script I've posted on the internet!).